Where is index i ? - K&R
I am reading the function on page 29 from "C programming" by K&R.
In this example:
int getline(char s[], int lim) {
    int c, i;
    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i) {
        s[i] = c;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

Inside the if (c == '\n') { ... } block, I don't understand how the statement s[i] = c; can work at that point. This code is outside the for loop that was assigning i, so where did the value for i come from?

int i is defined outside of the for loop. It's valid for the rest of the function.

s[i] = c; uses it

Note that the signature of this variant of getline() conflicts with the POSIX getline().    It probably isn't a major problem for you, but don't use this function except in the context of K&R exercises.  Rename it, if need be.

"Within the if statement, there is no index i?" - That's because int i has already been defined before the for loop . It's reusable within the loop's initialization routine and anywhere else in the function. "aren't indexes indexed by numbers?" - I'm not sure what you mean by this. I think you are suggesting that arrays are indexed by integers, which is true. i is an integer so its usage here is valid. In this example, i is essentially the number of characters read from the line. The parsed line itself is stored in the argument s[].

The if is outside the for loop am I right? so which 'element' is i accessing if i hasn't been given a value?

@wantice i has been given a value. It's assigned i = 0 in the for-loop's initialization routine, which runs one time before the loop iterates. By the time the if statement is reached, i has already been assigned 0 and has incremented however many times the loop iterated.

thank you, that made sense and cleared things up. don't know what the other commentators were going on about. thanks h053.

The reason that i is defined to be in scope for the whole function is that it is needed after the for loop, and in the days of K&R it wouldn't have been possible to write for(int i= ...) where the scope of i is restricted to the loop.

"don't know what the other commentators were going on about" - I guess they didn't understand that that was what was confusing you, because for experienced programmers it's so natural that it's impossible to imagine being confused by it. So they were trying to think of something else that might be confusing you. (But also because your question text doesn't clearly point at that problem - naturally, if you don't understand something like this, you won't be able to explain it properly.) I edited the question to try to explain your question more clearly.

This is a good example of how you should never write for loops. Get rid of this horrible book already.

Your confusion seems to be around how a for-loop's initialization routine works. A for-loop has 3 components in the initial parenthesis:

An initialization statement
A conditional expression
A post-iteration statement

The initialization statement always runs once before the conditional expression is evaluated.
If the conditional expression resolves to true, the loop iterates once, performs the post-iteration statement, and then re-evaluates the conditional expression. This repeats until the condition resolves to false or a break statement (or return) is encountered.
Note that each for-loop can be converted into an equivalent while-loop, and viewing this code as a while-loop may help clear up some of your confusion. Here is equivalent code using a while(true) construct to help illustrate the 3 parts of the for-loop that I mentioned.
int getline(char s[], int lim) {
    int c, i;

    // START: equivalent while-loop

    // An initialization statement
    i = 0; 

    while(true) {
        // A conditional expression
        if (lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
            // The condition is satisfied, run the loop body
            s[i] = c;
    
            // A post iteration statement
            ++i;
        } else {
            // The condition is no longer satisfied, exit the loop
            break;
        }
    }
    // END: equivalent while-loop

    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

Viewing the code above should help you see that int i is indeed assigned a value before it is referenced later in the function.
